# Insert html string with php code inside

Tags: php, jquery, html

Well, I need to insert a HTML string with php code inside in a form.

I have one form to create new users. Inside of it, I need to insert a role for this user, so I have some roles in my database to apply to him.

I have a html select field to do that, and a button to add a new rol. When I click in the button, I want to add a new select field to my form. But inside this code I have PHP code to show all roles. I try this way using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add-role').click(function (event) {
        var newRoleField = "<label for=\"usuario_perm_id\">ROLE <span class=\"required-field\"> * </span>:</label>" +
            "<select id=\"usuario_perm_id\" name=\"usuario_perm_id\" tabindex=\"7\">" +
            "<option <?php echo ($this->usuario[\"rol_id\"] == \"none\" ? 'selected=\"selected\"' : null); ?> value=\"none\">-- Seleccione un rol --</option>" +
            "<?php foreach ($this->roles as $rol): ?>" +
            "<option value=\"<?php echo $rol[\"rol_id\"]; ?>\" <?php echo ($this->usuario[\"rol_id\"] == $rol[\"rol_id\"] ? 'selected=\"selected\"' : null); ?>><?php echo $rol[\"nombre\"]; ?></option>" +
            "<?php endforeach; ?>" +
            "</select><br />";

        $('#new-roles').append(newRoleField);

        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault;
    });
});
```

And I get a new select field but inside it, the text:

`usuario["rol_id"] == "none" ? 'selected="selected"' : null); ?> value="none">-- Select role --`

Comment: exactly how do you expect your browser to run this php code? Are you going to require that all users run a custom browser that has a PHP engine built into them? remember... PHP is a server-side language. it's just random garbage as far as a browser is concerned....

Comment: PHP is interpreted server-side, not client-side.  You can't use JavaScript to include PHP code.  It's not clear what you're trying to do here, but you're either going to have to perform the server-side logic in a post-back of the page and re-render the page or include values from PHP into the JavaScript and use those values client-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. JavaScript (and thus also jQuery) runs **client side** and PHP runs **server side**. The browser has no idea how to handle any PHP you might insert.

A way to handle this, is to have jQuery query the server for the roles and have your server create a (PHP generated) list of roles. Check out [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I try to load a JS variable with my roles and then show that in my HTML select field.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert server side code (PHP) on the client (Javascript).

You can load the data from PHP into a JS variable when the page first loads up and then load from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works exactly with JQuery (I used it with pure JavaScript), but look for AJAX.